# HTML code that records site visits

Tags: html

I don't have any website creating experience and I am using a pre-made website and everytime someone goes on the website I want to add +1 to the total visits. And I want the total number of visits to be stored in a database. Any help? (I am not sure if HTML will do the job, like I said, no experience.) Thanks!

Comment: HTML cannot do the job, you need to head to w3schools and get yourself some knowledge in PHP and MySQL. good luck

Comment: Well this site sure does have a lot of stuff. I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can't really make your own with html, but you can go to [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com) and they will give you code to track you views there. You could also link it to google analytics and basically say in js, "if google analytics gets 1 visit, increment a div up by 1".

Comment: Gonna try it, thanks!